# DefinitlyTyped three.js doesn't work without node_module change

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am currently studying the three JS journey course form Bruno Simon. On top of that, I thought that it could be a good time to try to convert it into typescript so I could learn it and it would force me to go a little on my way and then get a deeper understanding

Because there is no native typescript version I donwloaded the famous definitelyTyped module for three jS but I have a problem... If I try to use the "THREE" namespace it doesn't work

```
import * as THREE from "three"
class Experience {

    scene: THREE.Scene // Namespace '"three"' has no exported member 'Scene'.ts(2694)

    constructor(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {        

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
    }
}

export default Experience
```

But that said, if go on node_modules/@types/three/index.d.ts and change

`export as namespace THREE`

to

`export as namespace Three`

the line suddenly work with

`scene: three.Scene`

So hourray, it work in local... but as soon as I'm going to upload it on github or live, index.d.ts is going to reverb back to it's original

Comment: This change shouldn't be necessary ... I wonder if it might be related to your `tsconfig.json` file? It might help if you can share that, and any bundler (Vite? Webpack?) config you might be using.